# sqoop import says can find Class <tablename>

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I installed `sqoop 1` on macbook, and did ant package. I then set `HADOOP_HOME` and `HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME` to existing hadoop home at `/usr/local/hadoop`.

When I ran the import command

```
bin/sqoop import --options-file /path/sqoop_params.txt --table recipe
```

where sqoop_params.txt contains username password, and postgres url.

it says

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class recipe not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
```

Why would sqoop mistake the table name for a java class?

Comment: Sqoop which version you are using and which document you are referring to use  --options-file command.

Answer (score 4):

Another simpler way to resolve this is to specify the bindir option on scoop which tells where to save the generated classes.

```
--bindir ./
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Sqoop generates code that can be used by MapReduce. To see the generated code, you can use the [code-gen tool](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.5/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_codegen_literal) to see the generated Java file. It should have the same name as the table you are importing normally. You can change the name using `--class-name`.
2. When using the LocalJobRunner, the generated class won't be part of the classpath some times. You can use `-libjars` to pass a jar to the MapReduce job.

   Example:

   1. Generate the jar: `sqoop codegen --connect "jdbc:mysql://example.com/sqoop" --username sqoop --password sqoop --table tbl`
   2. Look for the line in the output: `Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-abe/compile/4182409b0f559d7259a32a950627e1aa/tbl.jar`
   3. Use the above jar in your import commmand: `sqoop import -fs local -jt local -libjars /tmp/sqoop-abe/compile/4182409b0f559d7259a32a950627e1aa/tbl.jar --connect "jdbc:mysql://example.com/sqoop" --username sqoop --password sqoop --table tbl`

   For more information on using a local runner, check out this [blog post](http://ingest.tips/2015/02/06/use-sqoop-transfer-csv-data-local-filesystem-relational-database/).
3. I would not use a local mapreduce unless you have to. Check your mapreduce configuration and make sure `mapreduce.framework.name` is not set to local. For more information on this, check out the [hadoop docs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/).

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error. Please find below solution:-

*Use Below Command*

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/kpdatabase --username root 
--password rootpassword --table departments 
--bindir /usr/lib/sqoop/sqoop-1.4.6/lib/
```

Under the `--bindir` option give the path of `$SQOOP_HOME/lib`

`--bindir` informs sqoop to pick jar files from the location specified.